# Delete all <br> from a <div> using only Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I delete all `<br>` from a `<div>`, using only Javascript? Even a single `<br>` would work.

I know there is a way to do it with JQuery, but does anyone know a way to do it with Javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent_element');
var var1   = parent.getElementsByTagName('br');

for(var i = var1.length; i--;) {
    var1[i].parentNode.removeChild(var1[i]);
}
```

Note the reverse iteration, it's a live nodeList that is being modified, so it's a good idea to iterate in reverse.

Comment: This will remove all `<br />` tags, though.  Not just from a specific `<div>`

Comment: You can add a condition comparing the parentNode to the concerned DIV

Comment: FWIW, in most modern browsers you can do `var1[i].remove()`. It would need to be patched in older browsers.